# How to properly perform a new action in rails 3 with has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

OK Updating this question heavily based on progress made, also simplifying this by eliminating some info not pertinent to the problem.
I've been reviewing a lot of posts and railscasts about has_many :through but am still having an issue with a relatively simple /new form...  Here is the model:

**/app/models/user.rb   (Think of a user as a Doctor)**

```
  has_many :intakes
  has_many :patients, :through => :intakes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :intakes
```

**/app/models/intake.rb**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :patient
```

**/app/models/patient.rb**

```
has_many :intakes
has_many :users, :through => :intakes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :intakes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

Now, what I want to do is a simple **/patients/new** and have a form come up with some patient information and two drop-downs for Doctors (users).  The classical way to do this has been explained as:

**/app/controllers/patients_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.new
  2.times { @patient.intakes.build.build_user }
end
```

and in my view:
**/app/views/patient/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Patient" %>
<% end %>
```

And, finally, the fields partial:
**/app/views/patients/_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :intakes do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :first_name, "Cared for by" %>

    <%= select("patient[new_intake_attributes]", "user_id",
                            User.justthishosp(current_user.hospital).collect {
                    |user|
        [ user.first_name+" "+user.last_name, user.id]} ) %>
<% end %>
```

Now the above actually **does** cause the form to come up, and there **are** two "intake" html select elements!  Yea!  The problems are **A)** Only the *first* intake saves because **B)** The intake HTML format doesn't match what I see in all of the recommendations and **C)** I cannot determine the proper SELECT syntax to get the HTML format to match the recommendations.

The HTML that the above code produces is:

```
<label for="patient_intakes_attributes_0_first_name">Cared for by</label>
    <select id="patient_new_intake_attributes_user_id"
name="patient[new_intake_attributes][user_id]">
<option value="1"> </option>
<option value="4">Dan Akroyd</option>
<option value="2">Dave Collins</option></select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="patient_intakes_attributes_1_first_name">Cared for by</label>
    <select id="patient_new_intake_attributes_user_id" 
name="patient[new_intake_attributes][user_id]"><option value="1"> </option>
<option value="4">Dan Akroyd</option>
<option value="2">Dave Collins</option></select>
```

Note, specifically the form of the **select name**:
**name="patient[new_intake_attributes][user_id]"**

What they want in Advanced Rails Recipes is:
**name="patient[new_intake_attributes][][user_id]"**

And they way they say you should achieve that is with this select line:
**select("patient[new_intake_attributes][]", "user_id",**

However, that syntax gives me 
*`@patient[new_intake_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name*

I have tried so many variations of [] and patient, Patient, :patient and I cannot get anything to give me HTML that contains the empty [] after patient[new_intake_attributes]

So, at this point I've got TWO select boxes on the form, but only **one** saves because only one is being passed in the params hash. Which, BTW looks like this:

```
(PatientsController.create) params[:patient]: 
{"first_name"=>"Nine", "last_name"=>"Niner", ...,
 "new_intake_attributes"=>{"user_id"=>"2"}, "pri_loc_id"=>"6"}
```

and I need:

```
"new_intake_attributes"=>[{"user_id"=>"2"},{"user_id"=>"4"}]
```

Or *any* kind of collection which I could gladly process in my virtual method.

Whew!  Holy Smokes!
Thanks!

Comment: I advise you get the whole setup done for 1 intake. Then start doing it for more. You'll find your mistake on your own.

Comment: OK Jatin seems like a reasonable plan.  Thanks for taking the time to suggest.

Comment: OK I've got this working for a single intake, and I think I do know what the problem is, but can't find a solution.  This gives **two** drop-downs and works, but only the first drop-down's information is passed in the hash: `<%= f.fields_for :intakes do |builder| %>  ... <%= select("patient[new_intake_attributes]", "user_id",`  Whenever I try to do the recommended `select("patient[new_intake_attributes][]"` I just get **`@patient[new_intake_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name**.  _So close yet so far!_

Comment: I am unable to make sense out of your comment. Please update your question to reflect your problem and explain the expected behaviour & the result.

Comment: OK I've put it all in-line in the question! Thanks again!

Comment: It's been quite some time I worked on Rails & your problem is quite complex. I suggest you structure your question properly and raise a bounty.